# Tomcat not booting up Gradle Webapp

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a **Gradle webapp** having plugin **`war`** and **`jetty`** defined in **build.gradle**, as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

group = 'com.company'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
war.baseName = 'deploy'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/" }
}
dependencies {
    ..
}
```

When I perform a gradle build with **`jettyRunWar`**, as follows:

```
$ ./gradlew jettyRunWar
```

It build the application and deploy it to Jetty as expected.

Now I want to deploy the same application to **Tomcat7** as well, to do the same, I ran the gradle war task as follows:

```
$ ./gradlew war
```

after running the task, I can see the **deploy-1.0.war** inside `/Users/ArpitAggarwal/deploy/build/libs/` and when I tried to deploy it to Tomcat7, it's not picked up by Tomcat.

My question is - Do I need to apply any additional plugin to make the application deployable to Tomcat7?

Thanks.

Comment: No, You don't need any additional plugins, you should be able to deploy the same war to tomcat. Do you see any errors in tomcat startup?? I just created a war and deployed it to tomcat and it worked fine.

Comment: No errors in tomcat logs. Tomcat started fine without booting `.war`, I think Tomcat is not aware about `.war` file somehow. I tried with Eclipse as well, firstly "Add Web Module" is disabled and when I tried to add it using  "Add External Web Module", it not picking up.

Comment: I too deploy wars generated by gradle war plug-in to tomcat regularly. But gradle war plug-in does not do it for me. It just produces a war file in my build directory. I use bash or other tools to deploy, and with Tomcat default installation you can just copy the war into .../webapps/ and let Tomcat deploy it. There is a tomcat plug-in for gradle intended to deploy war files. There may be other ways to do it.

Comment: Ohh, i thought you are deploying it manually. `war` plug-in does not do that, it only creates a war file. So either you will have to deploy it manually or add some other plugin.

Comment: I tried deploying manually only but starting the server from Eclipse and `.war` was not picked up by Tomcat(not sure why), then I tried starting the server from command which works. But this give rise to another problem, for which I am writing an answer along with yours.

Comment: By manually means you need to copy it to tomcat webapps folder.

Comment: Exactly, I copied it to webapps folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`war` plug-in only creates a war, it doesn't deploy generated war to tomcat by itself.

You can create a task to deploy war to tomcat.

```
task deployToTomcat(type: Copy) {
    from war.archivePath
    into "${tomcatHome}/webapps"
}
```

You can also use [gradle-tomcat-plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin).

Comment: It's the answer to my next question, which I am about to ask ;)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is **`contextRoot`** of **`.war`** file. **Gradle** generates the contextRoot of .war file picking the **`war.baseName`** and **`version`**, so the contextRoot is changed to deploy-1.0 and the application is accessible at:

```
localhost:8080/deploy-1.0
```

Then I removed the version field from **`build.gradle`** which makes Gradle generate .war with contextRoot as deploy and application accessibility at:

```
localhost:8080/deploy/
```